# Allow user to edit tableview cell label when doing a long press

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I got a `tableView` and `tableView` cell setup (default values).

At the moment I got a button for adding a cell and set the `cell.textLabel.text`.

Is there a way to edit the `cell.textLabel.text` property by letting the user do a long click on  the cell to start editing (without using UIAlert)?

Comment: Change Label to TextField

Comment: change UILabel to UITextField, and initially disable the user interaction and while in editing mode enable the user interaction of the UITextField.

Comment: You must replace label with textfield as per your requirement.